# Python nested range function

Tags: python, range

What is the output of the following nested control structure in Python when executed?

```
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(x):
        print x,y
```

I know the answer is

```
1 0
2 0
2 1
```

But it is not clear for me why it is this output.
I know that the range(3) function would give you {0, 1, 2} so why is not the first output 0 0 instead of 1 0?

Comment: The interval [`[0, 0)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Interval_%28mathematics%29&oldid=692119288#Classification_of_intervals) is empty.

Comment: @Kay, +1 for basing this in mathematics. Also consider the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), as this is one of the examples presented for the `range()` function.

Answer (score 8):

Because range(0) returns an empty list `[]`, so the inner loop does nothing the first time it is run.

Answer (score 8):

Lets go through this

**First run**

```
x = 0
range(0) is []
the print is never reached
```

**Second Run**

```
x = 1
range(1) is [0] <-- one element
print is called once with 1 0
```

**Third Run**

```
x = 2
range(2) is [0,1] <-- two elements
print is called twice with 2 0 and 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes range(x) is [0,1,2,3,...x-1]
In short, range(x) is a list of x elements starting at 0 and incrementing.
As previously mentioned, this causes the first run of the second loop to never execute.